# Setting padding or margin around an element with css

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, margin, padding

I'm trying to customise pages on my Wordpress E-commerce site with CSS. In particular "variable" product pages like this one:

http://www.acdctv.co.uk/shop/satellite-dishes/kuma-12v-portable-flat-satellite-dish-only/

I'm trying to add some padding or margin above and below the main price element above the quantity selector (in this case £199.99) but nothing seems to be working.

In my custom.css file I have the following: 
`.single_variation .amount{font-size:1.6em; font-weight:bold;}` 
which I know is working to effect the element in question, but when I try to add `margin`, `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding`,`padding-top`, or `padding-bottom` even using `!important` I can't create the required effect. I can only seem to add padding to the left of the element.

Can anyone help me spot why this isn't working??

Comment: Thank you misterManSam and graphicdevine. `display:block;` was what was needed. Could have sworn I'd tried that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs `display: block`

CSS

```
.single_variation .amount {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` as well.  By default a `span` in an `inline` element:

```
.price {
  clear: left;
  margin: 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide `style` for the class `.price` in `custom.css` file like this

```
.price {
  padding: 0px 8px;
 }
```

This will reflect.